# Join With Where Clause - Nested Join/Where?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've been trying to look for examples that better match my specific needs but I can't seem to find any.

I've got the following SQL statement, which works like a charm:

```
SELECT
 customers.id,
 customers.customer_name,
 SUM(shipments.balance) AS shipmentBalance

 FROM customers

 LEFT JOIN shipments ON customers.id = shipments.bill_to
 GROUP BY customers.id, customers.customer_name
 ORDER BY shipmentBalance DESC;
```

But, I would like to be able to add a where condition to the JOIN, as I don't want ALL of the shipments balances being SUMMED up, rather only the ones that have balances greater than their related payment distribution amounts.

At this point, in a separate query, I can pull the shipments with balances that are greater than their payment distribution amounts using the following query:

```
SELECT
  shipments.id,
  shipments.pro_number,
  shipments.balance,
  SUM(payments_distributions.amount) AS Sum
FROM
  shipments

LEFT JOIN payments_distributions ON shipments.pro_number = payments_distributions.shipment_id
WHERE balance > (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(payments_distributions.amount),0) FROM payments_distributions WHERE payments_distributions.shipment_id = pro_number)
GROUP BY shipments.id,shipments.pro_number;
```

But I'm not sure how to combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the filter of the Shipment table in the ON clause:

```
SELECT
customers.id,
customers.customer_name,
SUM(shipments.balance) AS shipmentBalance
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN shipments ON customers.id = shipments.bill_to
   AND balance > (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(payments_distributions.amount),0) 
                  FROM payments_distributions 
                  WHERE payments_distributions.shipment_id = pro_number)
GROUP BY customers.id, customers.customer_name
ORDER BY shipmentBalance DESC;
```

Comment: I forgot to put in the question, do you know what I would need to add to list only the customers where the "shipmentBalance" is greater than 0?

Comment: Otherwise, this works perfectly and I thank you greatly for your help!

Comment: you can add at the end "HAVING SUM(shipments.balance) > 0"

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you so much for all of the help!